# Cookie doesn't send different domain django and react

Tags: cookies, django-rest-framework, vercel

I deployed my django rest framework application and react app separately on vercel.
So my urls for these are 'https://myproject.vercel.app/' and 'https://mybackendproject.vercel.app/'.

I use the sessionAuthentication and cookie for authentication. However, it seems that cookie is not set at frontend.
So I got the error "{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}"

I confirmed that the cookie is stored in developer's tools application section.
But when I send the post request like the below with cookies, it is not set.

```
useEffect(() => {
client
.get("/api/user", { 
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get("csrftoken"),
  },})
  .then(function (res) {
    setCurrentUser(true);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(Cookies.get("csrftoken"));
    setCurrentUser(false);
  });
```

}, []);

Is there any good way to send cookie from frontend to backend?
Currently, the cookie's samesite=lax.

I appreciate your opinion and advise!

Comment: That makes sense, cookies typically can not be inspected and send to a different domain.

Comment: Are 'https://myproject.vercel.app/' and 'https://mybackendproject.vercel.app/' completely different domain? I thought they are the same since they have '.vercel.app'.
In that case, how can I send cookies?
I checked the vercel domain but it seems impossible to deploy front-end and back-end at same domain.

Comment: That is because of the https://publicsuffix.org/. Check its effects on Cookies.